Error duplicate key value violates unique constraint "products_pkey" Detail: Key (product_id)=(2) already exists. Product extends AbstractEntity<Long>
Im trying to persist this entity in Db using a JPA repository:
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "product_id"))
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class Product extends AbstractEntity<Long> {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "product_number")
    private String productNumber;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "product_structure")
    private Integer productStructure;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_type_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "product_type_id")
    private ProductType type;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "epigraph_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "epigraph_id")
    private Epigraph epigraph;

    @Column(name = "dynamics_id")
    private String dynamicsId;

    @Column(name = "status_code")
    private Short statusCode;

    @Column(name = "state_code")
    private Short stateCode;

    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private OffsetDateTime creationDate;

    @Column(name = "init_date")
    private OffsetDateTime initialValidDate;

    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private OffsetDateTime finalValidDate;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_product_id_fk")
    private Product parentProduct;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ProductVersion.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "version_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "product_version_id")
    private ProductVersion productVersion;

    public void subscribeData(Product p) {
        if (p.getName() != null) {
            this.name = p.getName();
        }
        if (p.getProductStructure() != null) {
            this.productStructure = p.getProductStructure();
        }
        if (p.getProductNumber() != null) {
            this.productNumber = p.getProductNumber();
        }
        if (p.getType() != null) {
            this.type = p.getType();
        }
        if (p.getEpigraph() != null) {
            this.epigraph = p.getEpigraph();
        }
    }

}

The abstract entity Class is:
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public abstract class AbstractEntity<ID extends Serializable> extends AbstractPersistable<ID> {

    @Override
    public void setId(ID id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }

}

And repository is:

@Repository
public interface ProductsRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
}

the error that Jpa returns is:
2024-06-11T13:32:51.651+02:00 ERROR 17744 --- [nio-8001-exec-1] e.e.d.s.p.p.ProductsServiceImpl          : error at function saveProduct in ProductsServiceImpl stack trace:
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [products_pkey]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:269)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:232)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:565)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:660)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:410)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218)
at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy159.save(Unknown Source)
at es.exceltic.datamanager.services.products_services.products_service.ProductsServiceImpl.saveProduct(ProductsServiceImpl.java:90)
at es.exceltic.datamanager.controller.ProductsController.saveProduct(ProductsController.java:218)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:563)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:631)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:95)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:39)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3438)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4073)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:103)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:612)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:483)
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:480)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:329)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1425)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:477)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2234)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:1930)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:439)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:561)
... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "products_pkey"
Detail: Key (product_id)=(2) already exists.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:152)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
... 90 common frames omitted
can someone help me to understand why im getting this error, i debugged the code, and im ensure that the id of the entity that i want to save is null.

The error "duplicate key value violates unique constraint 'products_pkey'" indicates that you are trying to persist a Product entity that has a product_id value that already exists in the database. Check your database and see if the data already exists.
